# Passing a parameter into linq expression?

Tags: c#

I have the following code which converts a c# enum to javascript object but the types are invisible to the code and cause a compile time error. the types inside the stars are the problem, I guess that I need to pass the type into the linq expression but Im stock, does any one know how to do this?

```
public static string EnumToJsObj(Enum enumType)
{
    Type type = enumType.GetType();
    string strJS = string.Format("{{{0}}} ",
        string.Join(", ", Enum.GetNames(type).ToList().ConvertAll(key =>
        {
            return string.Format("{0} : {1}", key, (int)((***type***)Enum.Parse(typeof(***type***), key)));
        }).ToArray()));
}
```

Comment: What type do you want in `***type***`?

Comment: Type type = enumType.GetType();

Comment: Itried the genereic approach, it says "can not cast expression of type T to int"

Comment: @666 - Convert the enum instead of casting it (see my answer). As you can see in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx), System.Enum implements the `IConvertible` interface.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
public static string EnumToJsObj(Enum enumType)
{
    Type t = enumType.GetType();
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
            Enum.GetNames(t).ToDictionary(e => e, e => (int)Enum.Parse(t,e))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make your method to be a generic method:

```
public static string EnumToJsObj<T>(Enum enumType){ ... }
```

or you might be able to get away with using `System.Convert.ChangeType` instead of type casting.